# dependency injection of interface in Quartz.NET for Execute job

Tags: asp.net-core, quartz.net

i use asp.net core and Quartz.NET

in need inject interface like this

to execute job

```
    public class RemoveSmsSendQueueJob : IJob
{

    private readonly ISmsQueueService _smsQueueService;
    public RemoveSmsSendQueueJob(ISmsQueueService smsQueueService)
    {
        _smsQueueService = smsQueueService;
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {

        _smsQueueService.UpdateQueue();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

but get this error
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'Khanoumi.eShop.Notification.Service.RemoveSmsSendQueueJob' has been registered.'

i try add

services.AddSingleton<ISmsQueueService, SmsQueueService>();
or
services.AddScoped<ISmsQueueService, SmsQueueService>();
or
services.AddTransient<ISmsQueueService, SmsQueueService>();

in startup
but any time have other error

how can i fix this?

full error is :

Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Khanoumi.eShop.Notification.Service.RemoveSmsSendQueueJob Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Khanoumi.eShop.Notification.Service.RemoveSmsSendQueueJob': Unable to resolve service for type 'Khanoumi.eShop.Notification.Service.ISmsQueueService' while attempting to activate 'Khanoumi.eShop.Notification.Service.RemoveSmsSendQueueJob'.)'

Comment: it sounds like you are not deploying the custom objects WITH the quartznet server.  when the job(s) fire, there is code inside quartz.net that says "create these objects", but you haven't deployed those objects with quartz.net.

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that your job has not been added to the DI pipeline. Here is a quick way to add it in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddTransient<RemoveSmsSendQueueJob>();
```

Then you can inject later with no issue.

Comment: i do that but i get error (System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'Khanoumi.eShop.Notification.Service.RemoveSmsSendQueueJob' has been registered) error from JobFactory class , and NewJob method

Comment: @mahsa mohamad zadeh It is hard to say without seeing more of your code. Feel free to reference the way I implemented it here: https://github.com/crgolden/Services/tree/master/Job.Quartz

Answer (score 0):

You should try the new built-in integration available in 3.1. [Here is the documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html) how to get started.